# Template specialization and instantiation

Tags: c++, templates

These concepts is a bit unclear to me. Well, template instantiation's defined pretty well by `N4296::14.7 [temp.spec]`:

> The act of instantiating a function, a class, a member of a class
>   template or a member template is referred to as template
>   instantiation.

That's if we have a function/variable/class template, instantiation of the template is just creating an object or function. For instance:

```
template<typename T> class U{ };
U<int> a; //instantiation
```

But `N4296:14.7.1 [temp.inst]` says (Emphasize mine):

> Unless *a class template specialization has been explicitly*
>   *instantiated* (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class
>   template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
>   completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class
>   type affects the semantics of the program.

What's the definition of the instantiation of the *template specialization*, not just the instantiation of a template?

Comment: For the first case, the compiler won't implicitly instantiate a template definition that has already been instantiated explicitly; for the second, the compiler won't instantiate a template definition at all if the given arguments match a more specialized one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Instantiating a template specialization" typically refers to the process of implicit instantiation: substituting specific template arguments into a template definition to obtain an instantiated class, function, etc. Instantiating a template means instantiating a specialization of that template. Usually, the less precise phrasing is used when we're talking about some arbitrary instantiation in the context of language lawyering. You will also find the expression "instantiation of a template", which is synonymous with the instantiated specialization.

Comment: According to my understanding, this answer though not elaborate, seems to be not wrong. Not sure why it was down voted.

Answer (score 8):

Question:

> What's the definition of the instantiation of the template specialization, not just the instantiation of a template?

My understanding:

There is no such thing as instantiation of a template. You always instantiate a template specialization.

If you have:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo {};

Foo<int> foo;
```

you have instantiated the template specialization `Foo<int>`, not the template `Foo`.

### Update

Say you have the following class template:

```
template <typename T> struct Foo
{
   static int a;
};

int getNext()
{
   static int n = 0;
   return ++n;
}

template <class T> int Foo<T>::a = getNext();
```

**Explicit template instantiation**

You can create explicit instantiations of `Foo<char>` and `Foo<int>` by using:

```
template struct Foo<char>;
template struct Foo<int>;
```

Even if `Foo<char>` and `Foo<int>` are not used anywhere else in your code, the class template is instantiated for `char` and `int`.

**Explicit template specialization**

You can create explicit specializations of the class template by using:

```
template <> Foo<double> {};
```

**Use of `Foo`**

Now, let's see the use of `Foo`.

```
Foo<int> f1;    // An explicit instantiation has already been created.
                // No need for any further code creation.

Foo<double> f2; // An explicit specialization has already been created.
                // No need for any further code creation.

Foo<long> f3;   // There is no explicit instantiation or explicit specialization
                // Code needs to be created for Foo<long>
```

The third case, `Foo<long> f3;` triggers creation of the template specialization `Foo<long>`. I interpret the phrase *"class template specialization is implicitly instantiated"* to mean *"creation of `Foo<long>` from the class template."*.

Comment: _There is no such thing as instantiation of a template._ Are you sure about that? Because the first sentence of `N4296::14.7 [temp.spec]` told us that _The act of instantiating a function, a class, a member of a class template or a member template is referred to as **template instantiation**._

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, Good point. Let me read those sections of the standard a bit more carefully.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. But couldn't you clarify one more concept. We have two different concepts: `Partial specialization` and `explicit specialization`. Can we say that the `explicit specialization` is always the `partial specialization`?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv, partial specialization is neither an explicit instantiation nor an explicit specialization. For the purposes of this discussion, partial specialization is no different than an ordinary class template.