# Implicit instantiation of specialization

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

I can't understand why the standard first defines template instantiation ***for templates*** as follows `N3797::14.7/4 [temp.spec]`:

> The act of instantiating a function, a class, a member of a class
>   template or a member template is referred to as *template*
>   *instantiation*.

But further everywhere it uses the ***instatiation of the specialization***, like the following `N3797::14.7/4 [temp.spec]`:

> An instantiated *template specialization* can be either implicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.1) for a given argument list or be explicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.2).

I don't understand that. A template itself is a different concept than the template specilization, which could be an `explicit specialization` or a `partial specialization`. For instance `N3797::14.5.5/1 [temp.class.spec]`:

> The primary template shall be declared before any specializations of
>   that template.

My question is about why the Standard first declare the `instatiation` concept for templates, but further it applies that concept for template specializations?

Moreover `N3797::14.7/4 [temp.spec]` defines the specialization concept as follows:

> A specialization is a class, function, or class member that is either
>   instantiated or explicitly specialized (14.7.3).

So, the partial specialization is not a specialization, is it? I'm totally confused by those concepts. Couldn't you clarify it a bit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28469604/template-specialization-and-instantiation/28470316#28470316). 
And now,I try to answer this question again.

**A template is a type of infinite, so we can not instantiate a template, we can only be instantiated template specialization.**

- **Implicitly instantiated**, the current compilation unit requires the use of the template code, the compiler automatically instantiated template specialization.
- **Explicitly instantiated**, we manually enter the code causes the compiler to instantiate a template specialization.
- **explicit specialization**, given all the template parameters, and gives a non-generic code. Once the template type match, then instantiate this specialization.
- **Partial specialization**, some parameters are given template and gives a non-generic code. Once the template type match, then instantiate this specialization.

Comment: Thank you. The issue is it's just not quite clear described in the Standard.

Comment: Just look at the difinitions. Formally, a template and their specialization are different things and should be treated differently. Of course, if we assume that template instatiation, defined in `N3797::14.7/4 [temp.spec]` is completely the same thing as instantiation od the template specialization then it will be ok.